# Postgresql: Select sum with different conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have two table table:

I. Table 1 like this:

```
------------------------------------------
codeid | pos   | neg   | category 
-----------------------------------------
   1   | 10    |  3    | begin2016
   1   |  3    |  5    |  justhere
   3   |  7    |  7    |  justthere
   4   |  1    |  1    |  else
   4   | 12    |  0    |  begin2015
   4   |  5    |  12   |  begin2013
   1   |  2    |  50   |  now
   2   |  5    |  33   |  now
   5   |  33   |   0   |  Begin2011
   5   |  11   |   7   |  begin2000
```

II. Table 2 like this:

```
------------------------------------------
codeid | codedesc         | codegroupid 
-----------------------------------------
1      |  road runner     |    1
2      |  bike warrior    |    2
3      |  lazy driver     |    4
4      |  clever runner   |    1
5      |  worker          |    3
6      |  smarty          |    1
7      |  sweety          |    3
8      |  sweeper         |    1
```

I want to have one result like this having two (or more) conditions:

1. sum pos and neg where codegroupid IN('1', '2', '3')
2. BUt do not sum pos and neg if category like 'begin%'

So the result will like this:

```
------------------------------------------
codeid |      codedesc     | sumpos | sumneg
-----------------------------------------
 1   |  roadrunner       |  5     |  55   => (sumpos = 3+2, because 10 have category like 'begin%' so doesn't sum) 
 2   |  bike warrior     |  5     |  33
 4   |  clever runner    |  1     |  1
 5   |  worker           |  0     |  0   => (sumpos=sumneg=0) becase codeid 5 category ilike 'begin%'
```

Group by codeid, codedesc;
Sumpos is sum(pos) where category NOT ILIKE 'begin%', BUT IF category ILKIE 'begin%' make all pos values become zero (0);
Sumpos is sum(neg) where category NOT ILIKE 'begin%', BUT IF category ILKIE 'begin%' make all neg values become zero;

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Should the result have records for all codeids (1 - 8)? I thought maybe you only wanted records where codegroupid = 1 or 2, but your result is showing worker (codegroupid = 3). It is not clear if your result set is just showing a subset.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited coudegroupid to 1 or 2 or 3. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    b.codeid,
    b.codedesc,
    sum(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'begin%' THEN 0 ELSE a.pos END) AS sumpos,
    sum(CASE WHEN category LIKE 'begin%' THEN 0 ELSE a.neg END) AS sumneg
FROM
    table1 AS a
    JOIN
    table2 AS b ON a.codeid = b.codeid
WHERE b.codegroupid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
    b.codeid,
    b.codedesc;
```